# Center Point In Circular Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, geometry

Suppose a point initially located at (x,y) moves to (x',y') in a circular motion with angular velocity $w$. Then, the center of this circular motion (x*,y*) can be found by the following:

[image]

where $\theta = w \Delta t$.

I really do not understand how this relation holds. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I would highly advise you to learn a bit of MathJax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), instead of uploading images.

Comment: What reference did you find this in? By the way, it is a geometry question, not a physics one.

Comment: Mathjax is the *site standard* for mathematics.  Images of equations are very, very strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but it may help show the formula is reasonable.

[image]

First there is a line segment connecting $(x,y)$ and $(x^{'},y^{'})$. The center of the circle is somewhere on the line that bisects that segment and is perpendicular to it.

The center of the segment is $$(x_0,y_0) = \left(\frac{x+x^{'}}{2},\frac{y+y^{'}}{2}\right)$$

The vector from $(x,y)$ to $(x^{'},y^{'})$ is

$$\left(x^{'}-x, y^{'} - y\right)$$

You can do a dot product to show that this vector is perpendicular to that one.

$$(X,Y) = (y^{'} - y, x-x^{'})$$

So the line containing the center of the circle is the set of vectors

$$(x_0,y_0) + a (X,Y)$$

where a is a real number. So you need to find $a_0$, the value of a that matches the center of the circle.

$$(x^{*},y^{*}) = \left(\frac{x+x^{'}}{2},\frac{y+y^{'}}{2}\right) + a_0 * (y^{'} - y, x-x^{'})$$

To do that, you might think about lines from the center of the circle that pass through $(x,y)$ and $(x^{'},y^{'})$.